# Constant in SQL-query

Tags: php

How can I use a constant inside of a SQL-query? After som searching I found a tip to use concatenation like: `. DB_TABLE .` but this isn't working because I get this kind of error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean in`

This don't work:

```
$sql_col_1 = "SELECT * FROM" . DB_TABLE .  "WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 11 ORDER BY RAND() ;";
```

But this do:

```
$sql_col_1 = "SELECT * FROM buildings WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 11 ORDER BY RAND() ;";
```

Comment: `$DB_TABLE = 'user';` and then `$sql_col_1 = "SELECT * FROM " . $DB_TABLE .  " WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 11 ORDER BY RAND() ;";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a space before and after `DB_TABLE`:

```
$sql_col_1 = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_TABLE . " WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 11 ORDER BY RAND() ;";
                           ^                ^
```

With your original code, if DB_TABLE was let's say buildings, your code would be rewritten to (After concatenation):

```
$sql_col_1 = "SELECT * FROMbuildingsWHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 11 ORDER BY RAND() ;";
```

^ This would be the reason why your SQL is causing errors.

The easiest way to debug this in the future, is simply `echo` out `$sql_col_1`. Adding `echo $sql_col_1; exit;` right after, will show you the actual query that's being run.

Answer (score 2):

Need space after `FROM` and before WHERE

```
echo $sql_col_1 = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_TABLE .  " WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 11 ORDER BY RAND()";
                                ^^               ^^
```

Your's query fails and you got fatal error!!